# Apache2 - Redirect to external Server for several domains

Tags: debian, web-server, redirect, apache2

my goal is to setup a webserver, that redirects http requests to another server.
For example, when an URL/Domain changes.

I want to create an CNAME Record for the old domain to the redirectserver (that i want to setup here) and this server redirects to the new domain.
I got it working for one domain - but I only get the first redirect. I cant differ between different hostnames in the Servername.

regardless what Domain is call, I only get the redirect to the first host (although the ServerName doesn't match) to https://newhost.example.com/.

My configuration is the following.

```
#first host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.example.com
    redirect 301 / https://newhost.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

#second host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.example.com
    redirect 301 / https://different.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently only testing on http, would like to implement https after that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with switching to the module mod_rewrite and used the following configuraiton:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.example.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test1\.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ https://newhost.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```